# Python and Selenium to access Saved Webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python and Selenium and want to test it on a saved website so I don't keep generating a lot of login requests and get locked out. I have:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("WEBSITE URL")
```

How would this differ with a file location instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a `example.html` which resides in a folder in my local machine.

I do this to get it using Selenium :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("C:\\Users\\****\\OneDrive-abc\\Desktop\\Automation\\example.html")
```